# Insert and replace data php sql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, sql-server

```
TABLE1: table1ID | studentnum | lname | fname | mname
TABLE2: table2ID | studentnum | remarks | others

//THIS IS MY FORM 1
$sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE1 (studentnum, lname, fname, mname)
VALUES ('$studentnum','$lname','$fname','$mname')";

$sql1 = $sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE2 (studentnum)
VALUES ('$studentnum')";



mysql_select_db('databasename');
    $retval = mysql_query($sql);          
    if(!$retval ) {
    die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $retval = mysql_query($sql1);          
    if(!$retval ) {
    die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }

echo "Data added successfully!";
    mysql_close($conn);  


SAMPLE OUTPUT:

TABLE1: 

table1ID | studentnum | lname | fname | mname
1        |    1001    |  My   |   An  | Swer


TABLE2: 

table2ID | studentnum | remarks | others
1        |    1001    |         |
```

Table2 now has studentnum encoded data from table 1. 
    I want this output, how can I do this from FORM 2

```
//sample output with form1 and form2 values
table2ID | studentnum | remarks | others
1        |    1001    |   good  |  N/A
```

I have 2 tables and 2 forms please see my codes above. Anyone can help me how can I do this?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Why would you enter a partial record into table2 before you have the data to insert there? It is meaningless.  Just create the record in table two once you have the form data ready to populate it.  If you have both table1 and table 2 data available at time script is run, you could also insert across a join to add records to both tables at once.

Answer (score 0):

Check the values you get back from the database and when they are empty you can replace the values with something to hold their place(good or N/A) using the php empty() function. 
See this [page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).
Also if all the information you need is not in TABLE2 consider using an [SQL join.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)